# Implementing a Skiplist Node in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct, skip-lists

I am looking to create a a Skip List data structure. Here is a snapshot of code that I have so far for Node.

```
    #define MAX_HEIGHT = 20;
    struct Node {
         int i;
         Node *nodes[20];
     }
```

I understand that if I used vector in this case it would be far better as you can dynamically change its size. I was wondering where would I go if I wanted to use arrays.

I am new to C++, so I am wondering whether it is possible to assign the size of the array at a later instance. Say, I wanted to add another node that only has size 2 array of pointers.

Comment: Have you heard of the [new operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/) which dynamically allocates memory in the heap ?

Comment: Hmm, I have. In the example from the documentation. From my understanding it is creating new MyClass structs. But I am wondering whether it is possible to make, for example, a new Node where the size of nodes is 10, instead of 20.

Comment: To create an array of dynamic size say for your class `Node`, do this `Node *node_list = new Node [size];` where `size` is any variable which may be 10,20 or anything. __Advantage of this is `size` is determined at runtime and the memory is allocated in the heap.__

Comment: Huh, You mean within struct correct?

Comment: You said _"assign the size of the array at a later instance"_ , when you have this so called **instance** make the array using the `new operator` as I mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: Thanks. I think I know what you mean now.

Comment: @PRP better to use "Dynamic storage" than heap. C++ can be implemented without a heap.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the height to the constructor of the node being created, inside the constructor you just **dynamically allocate an array of pointers of `Node`**, and don't forget to free that memory in the destructor:

```
struct Node {
    int i;
    int height;
    Node* *nodes;
    Node(int h) {
        nodes = new Node*[h];
        height = h;
    }
    ~Node() {
        delete [] nodes;
    }
};
```